# Как авторизоваться на сайте со всплывающим окном авторизации?

Tags: python, requests

Всем привет! Есть сайт ,

> https://www.wg-gesucht.de/en/

мне нужно авторизоваться в нем через Python и отправлять сообщения. Делаю я это с помощью python requests.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.wg-gesucht.de/en/'


user_agent_val = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'

# Создаем сессию и указываем ему наш user-agent
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url, headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent_val
})

session.headers.update({'Referer':url})

session.headers.update({'User-Agent':user_agent_val})

# Получаем значение _xsrf из cookies
_xsrf = session.cookies.get('_xsrf', domain=".de")

# Осуществляем вход с помощью метода POST с указанием необходимых данных 
post_request = session.post(url, {
     'backUrl': 'https://www.wg-gesucht.de',
     'username': '',
     'password': '',
     '_xsrf':_xsrf,
     'remember':'yes',
})

#Вход успешно воспроизведен и мы сохраняем страницу в html файл
with open("hh_success.html","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(post_request.text)
```

Но я никак не пойму, он заходит и авторизуется или нет??? И как взять ссылку окна авторизации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует посмотреть, какие нужно передать значения методом `POST`. Если Вы открываете в браузере `Google Chrome`, то нажмите `F12`, или `Просмотреть код`. Затем перейдите во вкладку Network и авторизуйтесь на сайте. После авторизации нажмите на файл в таблице `Name` слева (чаще всего это самый первый файл, он может называться `login/`). Прокрутите до самого низа и найдите блок `Form Data`. Здесь вы можете найти все данные, которые следует передать, чтобы успешно авторизоваться на сайте, там же есть и уникальный токен о котором вы спрашивали в другом ответе.

В примере ниже значения взяты для сайта https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ (вы же должны передать те, которые есть в блоке `Form Data`)

```
...
data = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': session.cookies.get('csrftoken'), 
        'auth-username': 'your_login', 
        'auth-password': 'your_password', 
        'login_view-current_step': 'auth'
}

session.headers.update({'Referer': url})
post_request = session.post(url, data=data)
...
```

Плюс ко всему можете открыть файл `hh_success.html` (находится в той же директории, где и `.py` скрипт) и посмотреть его содержимое, корректно ли авторизовались и тд...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно для такого решения стоит использовать Chrome Headless. Там авторизоваиться, и в дальнейшем использовать для получения информации. Хотя, после авторизации, лучше взять токен и потом использовать `requests`

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом токен?