# Выходит 403 ошибка, когда заливаю бота на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, requests, pythonanywhere

Всем привет! Есть код, который авторизуется на сайте.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
user_agent_val = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
session.headers.update({'User-Agent':user_agent_val})
datas = {
    'login_email_username':'<my-email>',
    'login_password': '<my-password>'
}
url = 'https://www.wg-gesucht.de/'
s = requests.Session()
loging = s.post(url, data = datas)
f = open('result.txt','w+', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(loging.text)
f.close()
```

Залил этот код на pythonanywhere, и выходит такая ошибка

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 507, in send
> raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.wg-gesucht.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to pr
> oxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Как я понял, сам сайт не дает доступ и блокирует? В чем еще может быть причина и как ее решить?

Answer (score 2):

Код HTTP 403 говорит о том, что произошла ошибка в GET/POST или других методах отправки, и сервер не дает отправить данные (От того он и называется Forbidden).
Скорее всего сервер сайта, на который вы отправляете запрос, не принимает данные конкретно с PythonAnywhere. Попробуйте другой хостинг (Heroku например).

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно должно быть так, как указал @AlexVid. Вам не следовало изменять строку с записью файла в `result.txt`. Нужно было записывать все данные в файл `.html`, и тогда смогли бы увидеть ошибку, и с чем она связана.

```
with open("hh_success.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(post_request.text)
```

Там написано:

[image: 1]

```
Ошибка проверки CSRF. Запрос прерван.
Вы видите это сообщение, потому что этот HTTPS-сайт требует, чтобы ваш веб-браузер отправил
заголовок Referer, но он не был отправлен. 
Этот заголовок требуется по соображениям безопасности, чтобы гарантировать, что ваш браузер 
не будет взломан третьими лицами.
Если вы настроили свой браузер на отключение заголовков «Referer», пожалуйста, повторно включите их, 
по крайней мере, для этого сайта, или для соединений HTTPS, 
или для запросов «того же происхождения».
```

Это означает, что следовало написать эту строку перед методом `POST`:

```
session.headers.update({'Referer': url})
post_request = session.post(url, data=datas)
```

Тем более я Вам приводил пример в этом вопросе: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190714/Как-авторизоваться-на-сайте-со-всплывающим-окном-авторизации/1190782#1190782](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190714/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/1190782#1190782)