# Как создать запрос для регистрации на сайте?

Tags: python, requests

Пытаюсь зарегистрироваться на сайте https://www.nike.com/ru/register
Но как-то выходит 403 ошибка и я не понимаю, что делать. Помогите, пожалуйста))

```
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()
url = "https://www.nike.com/ru/login"
headers = {"Host": "www.nike.com",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
"DNT": "1",
"Accept": "image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "no-cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "image",
"Referer": "https://www.nike.com/ru/login",
"Accept-Language": "ru,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8",
"Cookie": r'AnalysisUserId=217.212.224.173.129931592041877528; s_ecid=MCMID%7C66974607684977921241364755869311046178; AMCVS_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1; NIKE_COMMERCE_COUNTRY=RU; NIKE_COMMERCE_LANG_LOCALE=ru_RU; anonymousId=CB1306CA28BA0F8A17383B3BBAEBC64D; _gcl_au=1.1.11906615.1592041885; _scid=35ceaaf4-787d-4a93-ba79-37e22dd26d0f; RES_TRACKINGID=872440221857167; bluecore_nv=false; CONSUMERCHOICE=ru/ru_ru; siteCatalyst_sample=83; dreamcatcher_sample=41; neo_sample=29; NIKE_CART=b:c; guidU=e38ff9b9-7a65-4e8a-d5f4-df4be36ce777; sq=3; optExiD=mex-user-dev; TT3bl=false; TURNTO_VISITOR_SESSION=1; _fbp=fb.1.1592300416800.806964755; _ga=GA1.2.25565056.1593722826; AMCV_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1994364360%7CMCMID%7C66974607684977921241364755869311046178%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1593731377s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C3.4.0%7CMCIDTS%7C18446%7CMCAAMLH-1594328977%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1594328977%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI; APID=7BD48FF2F985213006A7B7E0A39CBB1F.sin-346-app-ap-0; bluecoreNV=false; lls=3; geoloc=cc=RU,rc=,tp=vhigh,tz=GMT+3,la=59.89,lo=30.26; ResonanceSegment=1; cpd=member|nikecom>member>settings; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU1EVTNOakZtWlRjdE5USm1ZUzAwTW1VeUxXRmxOemN0TkRCaU9XUTJZbUl4WW1RMA; _sctr=1|1603227600000; s_sess=%20c51%3Dhorizontal%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20tp%3D1741%3B%20s_ppv%3Dnikecom%25253Echeckout%25253Eshipping%252C44%252C44%252C763%3B; bc_nike_russia_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22172ad174bcf941-0f70df643e80e8-f7d123e-144000-172ad174bd0acd%22%2C%22cart_total%22%3A%206999%2C%22ch%22%3A%20%222143890453%22%7D; nike_locale=ru%2Fru_ru; _gid=GA1.2.1127679783.1603443049; ppd=pdp|snkrs>pdp>air%20jordan%201%20high%20og; guidS=ef18f5fb-1293-4faa-d1b8-b67e14443e16; _uetsid=f6795e20176711eb8591e3a556c36bd4; _uetvid=245eaa20edb00722112688b8c6746cc0; _aw_m_16335=16335_1603443072_72581cb557ca88124f2c47dd845e74ff; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9SGpDRlZvcFU5a3kyckZYVHNyRUt6TklHbi1zUEpadVYmbj1VVG5uUzR6T0h2ME83MGkxZUxubWJnJm09NyZ0PUFBQUFBRi1XbnZn; guidSTimestamp=1603705490286|1603706618294; AKA_A2=A; feature_enabled__as_nav_rollout=true; audience_segmentation_performed=true; bm_sz=519DF4866192F07F0D39B1D82B4CA8E2~YAAQFFzaF94b4mB1AQAAzvIdZglIbOqwDiaUPorJaRziLnVxfbwErDqd0okLpLaNBuOSxtGh2rv1ZgVqZe74OkIKCXjVkgfZEUwnmhBq70NC9/e008g5o4O0DL+mNWx6TNR+gFZz1osgZE20J8Ai6yvmpbcTYzQWfD6BlxkGmz9U8RdVU7CI2AU02qdXqT7+BliRrtCWpH69M25sjkLFP6rODeeSIL+UxjgT46fsbk9zjobAot1sKQOEOyfuUsArCE7BRUy0RbOM8KYM2HJIXd6BSPpJPcbq6Tk=; bm_mi=06CB46822CD7BDC60239BEF038FE2E7F~3PM+xjR7WFULbpaQnOwyXVrXxlws51EjHVaCSLESP/LABHB4jRqLfa7f9O7qrnZQW2ii/AWPVPGS2NbcL7vBIASyF5rVJ9KvSy04nU0fJDjc8gXFURwQ7KjGX9m15abm0v10CW4vbbOTAkzR8pXsiNgLtFCQ3/sLFwsczaLEPg3fEeNiOOzrkVByZQrgRMoy6uz5qZwFfJF7bF2rwBizR978jblqq7HKjxL7CLLkvj4=; ak_bmsc=7DF019BB51A958C5EF3246B59766C6AC17DA5C146D120000E811975F47DFF623~plW455saGGWjx89NV5yJZZ/INX7e4AlwlcoGwrw1P+EXCy4Pj/jhIHcH4mUux9Vm3hZt8nDq0xna699joZG4KMh1/M6FZrDtEZ3q1gdu5dd45ksru1CuGmAF9CsYzq+pVu5Qh7vV6uEY/K/uGjC6dkpkmtr+e6CG/BS2T/tg2GM2p59kanFDbX4Ogn47yBqMobZs7aQypvoUraO3+1/iWqUC8AdfmYWlx9mMctRalBqHq0LtSSpdzfs2rhajHaJ2DY; _abck=227BFC68D0B6E0FE84B792D8A68D4D78~-1~YAAQFcMTAugE1WN1AQAAqw8hZgTs827V70wxDg8gv9nMc2Ja+Y4F6RdzgvIDIWJuzeCxHqZ8DsrDtj4h5JNEsmvioe9Q2ap57NP2GRxuArfS1mtgRjv69FaAx1kijV5WqLFVZlgqSp0RmoXygF6OO69h2lZ92UGFBWmqTZ147KChMB+psbGnRDTpK/MHDREVHU4ZzpK65EzWo+vqHTvbDV95712FY0ckR8JuNMNRONF3OiJKRioJeXqd6qY9Sdcej5FnsZ7JP9UYhP/f9AJzM3d2vMIa05vmSbVnOkuvJiK7HrJo4PklPC1sTclOc2rNBZxb4vZRxW2ZPOeUbWUnMFxJ0Xd14DxpfyPZ0IqcEBou1sugnX2C86+G0y/IY0cSj+OuxkkdOEBnc+zeGZSwZ+nUXK5ysJr4jAKUwGqQUjSC1nfWocd4VHCN+xnxAT7TKmO9NlDJUZI4Qw==~-1~-1~-1; bm_sv=7420B4C6E7451ADD86B8A63932876996~kki6GRvxu6/a312Xy1TkzjIB/N3gkY1Lpws23VCnkS7rPJuHDc6tZ9mmPviK0OxXsHwoZ25CaGW61YSiak3bM6r4JwZgP5K7tONlmrVL7CnklSC4pB113iYpy4CILrUvinZMITK5mlNqcVfv+xuRmw==; slCheck=If04FzGIifPr5iKvueUS0l0NKyB9y/P3j2RcS50U7AGUPb/tZJ5jqqOGRHZLJ06mgphFk26XJUwBIbJlmmOrW89P9soiGM2ip45mLRoCPHCwRi83pRPCEYYMT5FIN/gQ; llCheck=lVWanCW9uk59PetmEI6hU6968NnX3yViX65hPzwFkFf99Gd4CWft1+1b/QQdx2qy8/SZtv26CGgDegCHlU+PsqXAuC3yK29IaKTTqecLMj4b2meTXAmcaI5llRD3JoRZijRxhi6hbRV3DU7EAj0YSursdqON6yd7q1agMS7gPII=; sls=3; RT="z=1&dm=nike.com&si=6759c1d1-2542-4e30-b72f-38abfb13dcde&ss=kgqv12sj&sl=1&tt=2uf&bcn=%2F%2F6852bd10.akstat.io%2F&ld=2ur&nu=207re2x3&cl=7wn&ul=4fwh"',
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
visitor = response.headers['X-Request-Id']

url = "https://unite.nike.com/access/users/v1?appVersion=839&experienceVersion=839&uxid=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web&locale=ru_RU&backendEnvironment=identity&browser=Google%20Inc.&os=undefined&mobile=false&native=false&visit=18&visitor=" + visitor +"&language=ru&uxId=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web"
headers = {"Host": "unite.nike.com",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
"DNT": "1",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Origin": "https://www.nike.com",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Referer": "https://www.nike.com/",
"Accept-Language": "ru,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8",
"Cookie": r'AnalysisUserId=217.212.224.173.129931592041877528; s_ecid=MCMID%7C66974607684977921241364755869311046178; AMCVS_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1; NIKE_COMMERCE_COUNTRY=RU; NIKE_COMMERCE_LANG_LOCALE=ru_RU; anonymousId=CB1306CA28BA0F8A17383B3BBAEBC64D; _gcl_au=1.1.11906615.1592041885; _scid=35ceaaf4-787d-4a93-ba79-37e22dd26d0f; RES_TRACKINGID=872440221857167; CONSUMERCHOICE=ru/ru_ru; siteCatalyst_sample=83; dreamcatcher_sample=41; neo_sample=29; NIKE_CART=b:c; guidU=e38ff9b9-7a65-4e8a-d5f4-df4be36ce777; sq=3; _fbp=fb.1.1592300416800.806964755; _ga=GA1.2.25565056.1593722826; AMCV_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1994364360%7CMCMID%7C66974607684977921241364755869311046178%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1593731377s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C3.4.0%7CMCIDTS%7C18446%7CMCAAMLH-1594328977%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1594328977%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI; APID=7BD48FF2F985213006A7B7E0A39CBB1F.sin-346-app-ap-0; lls=3; geoloc=cc=RU,rc=,tp=vhigh,tz=GMT+3,la=59.89,lo=30.26; ResonanceSegment=1; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU1EVTNOakZtWlRjdE5USm1ZUzAwTW1VeUxXRmxOemN0TkRCaU9XUTJZbUl4WW1RMA; _sctr=1|1603227600000; s_sess=%20c51%3Dhorizontal%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20tp%3D1741%3B%20s_ppv%3Dnikecom%25253Echeckout%25253Eshipping%252C44%252C44%252C763%3B; _gid=GA1.2.1127679783.1603443049; guidS=ef18f5fb-1293-4faa-d1b8-b67e14443e16; guidSTimestamp=1603705490286|1603706618294; feature_enabled__as_nav_rollout=true; audience_segmentation_performed=true; bm_sz=519DF4866192F07F0D39B1D82B4CA8E2~YAAQFFzaF94b4mB1AQAAzvIdZglIbOqwDiaUPorJaRziLnVxfbwErDqd0okLpLaNBuOSxtGh2rv1ZgVqZe74OkIKCXjVkgfZEUwnmhBq70NC9/e008g5o4O0DL+mNWx6TNR+gFZz1osgZE20J8Ai6yvmpbcTYzQWfD6BlxkGmz9U8RdVU7CI2AU02qdXqT7+BliRrtCWpH69M25sjkLFP6rODeeSIL+UxjgT46fsbk9zjobAot1sKQOEOyfuUsArCE7BRUy0RbOM8KYM2HJIXd6BSPpJPcbq6Tk=; bm_mi=06CB46822CD7BDC60239BEF038FE2E7F~3PM+xjR7WFULbpaQnOwyXVrXxlws51EjHVaCSLESP/LABHB4jRqLfa7f9O7qrnZQW2ii/AWPVPGS2NbcL7vBIASyF5rVJ9KvSy04nU0fJDjc8gXFURwQ7KjGX9m15abm0v10CW4vbbOTAkzR8pXsiNgLtFCQ3/sLFwsczaLEPg3fEeNiOOzrkVByZQrgRMoy6uz5qZwFfJF7bF2rwBizR978jblqq7HKjxL7CLLkvj4=; ak_bmsc=7DF019BB51A958C5EF3246B59766C6AC17DA5C146D120000E811975F47DFF623~plW455saGGWjx89NV5yJZZ/INX7e4AlwlcoGwrw1P+EXCy4Pj/jhIHcH4mUux9Vm3hZt8nDq0xna699joZG4KMh1/M6FZrDtEZ3q1gdu5dd45ksru1CuGmAF9CsYzq+pVu5Qh7vV6uEY/K/uGjC6dkpkmtr+e6CG/BS2T/tg2GM2p59kanFDbX4Ogn47yBqMobZs7aQypvoUraO3+1/iWqUC8AdfmYWlx9mMctRalBqHq0LtSSpdzfs2rhajHaJ2DY; llCheck=lVWanCW9uk59PetmEI6hU6968NnX3yViX65hPzwFkFf99Gd4CWft1+1b/QQdx2qy8/SZtv26CGgDegCHlU+PsqXAuC3yK29IaKTTqecLMj4b2meTXAmcaI5llRD3JoRZijRxhi6hbRV3DU7EAj0YSursdqON6yd7q1agMS7gPII=; nike_locale=ru/ru_ru; _aw_m_16335=16335_1603443072_72581cb557ca88124f2c47dd845e74ff; _uetsid=f6795e20176711eb8591e3a556c36bd4; _uetvid=245eaa20edb00722112688b8c6746cc0; bc_nike_russia_triggermail=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22172ad174bcf941-0f70df643e80e8-f7d123e-144000-172ad174bd0acd%22%2C%22cart_total%22%3A%206999%2C%22ch%22%3A%20%221063175139%22%7D; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9RFVwcFRlcGM5alZneHpTbHJLQzc5UkpZSDhGOGg2UEombj11c2F5RElDeHJKTDB4WFRSQm43QWZnJm09NyZ0PUFBQUFBRi1YRXJv; ppd=member|nikecom>member>settings; cpd=member|nikecom>member>profile; visitData={"visit":"1","visitor":"901a2ecf-adb2-4a69-9743-3ae7031887d3"}; AKA_A2=A; _gat_UA-167630499-3=1; bm_sv=7420B4C6E7451ADD86B8A63932876996~kki6GRvxu6/a312Xy1TkzjIB/N3gkY1Lpws23VCnkS7rPJuHDc6tZ9mmPviK0OxXsHwoZ25CaGW61YSiak3bM6r4JwZgP5K7tONlmrVL7ClEoNc72oVAGsTm7mVuBUPyz8R0hYXpxbO3L7o8WcPlEA==; RT="z=1&dm=nike.com&si=6759c1d1-2542-4e30-b72f-38abfb13dcde&ss=kgqxd7ei&sl=0&tt=0&bcn=%2F%2F6852bd10.akstat.io%2F&ld=1tdvq&nu=207re2x3&cl=3av"; _abck=227BFC68D0B6E0FE84B792D8A68D4D78~-1~YAAQFFzaFykI42B1AQAAgqtaZgR5la2vUrsO5x5i0Pj2b1yMrx6bVd6yHb0PhPIjQqz/GS7Jk59uhwUN2p1tfYBhdnlSLR0yP2JnAiWRxmZYXHs5rBdozJmCTQKNQwtQfSpnnJa7SPMuLBeeUydoqDzru10ctFracNUncaDJL+BKkjK/kK/59rgb/k7uzvauKlEE9DDnFKfstkfLmzkHmfFGFLTZcZ5fLx7PgOqveMjzYcBTh6GBo9rspfhj5qiUO1+IGfWMZ6zoBPZe9Y7MdjdtQEM6zd5aXXepUfwxSKs/HQSALlvkwwkqrJ8Sc5WBI+dPYrmQPeZHNfw47qjbVRiYotrxsVU7w1b2dW5FVjJYfMYuuZ1ZPIS6TZYCZV8KlumCCuz6pwkdqzN9w0Y9sWY44vBFzsO4m0+kuWQXzW9tOKueJiSAnhL1SJJHlelapayVbZIHkSdw~-1~-1~-1',
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Content-Length": "422"}

data = {"country":"RU","emailOnly":"false","firstName":"Roberto","gender":"M","lastName":"Pisko","locale":"ru_RU","password":"HUiNa228t","receiveEmail":"false","registrationSiteId":"nikedotcom","welcomeEmailTemplate":"","emailAddress":"ssalna3@xaut.xyz","ssn":"null","username":"ssalna3@xaut.xyz","account":{"email":"ssalna3@xaut.xyz","passwordSettings":{"password":"HUiNa228t","passwordConfirm":"HUiNa228t"}},"dateOfBirth":"2000-04-12"}


response = session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Вам нужно зарегистрироваться или авторизоваться?

Comment: Зарегистрироваться

Comment: Если можете заодно и показать авторизацию, то я буду только рад!

Comment: Я это спросил потому, что не очень понял смысла именно регистрации через скрипт. Если Вы конечно не хотите зарегать овердофига аккаунтов

Comment: Я - шизик. Хочу регистрироваться)

Comment: Бывает. Ща минут 10 подождите )

Comment: Одну минуту. Сейчас я Вам помогу, я тут на стеке помогал одному человеку. Сейчас найду ссылку. И вам даже не пригодится селениум))

Comment: Очень жду ответа)

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy, Я пожалуй пополню ряды ожидающих

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190808/Выходит-403-ошибка-когда-заливаю-бота-на-pythonanywhere/1191578#1191578. Там в моем ответе еще и ссылку на предыдущий пост оставил. Там более подробно описано, что нужно делать) Отпишите потом, или это то, что вы искали.

Comment: Ну, это не помогло пока что, но я буду разбираться дальше

Comment: @Jairman, да, я сначала не заметил, что вы указали `регистрация`, а не `авторизация`, но по крайней мере там есть подсказка про ошибку 403:)

Comment: Ну, подсказка-то есть, а вот свою проблему я не пофиксил ещё

Comment: Вероятно не просто будет сделать это, поскольку разрабы, похоже, сделали все, чтобы этого не происходило. В любом случае удачи

Comment: Уже вот так делаю https://pastebin.com/x0tQjLaG, но получается You don't have permission to access от сайта

Comment: @Jairman, вам удалось решить свою проблему? Если да - напишите здесь пожалуйста ответ. Мне самому стало интересно, как реализовать регистрацию на сайте.

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy Нет, не понял, как обходить такую защиту

Answer (score 1):

Сначала качаете [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.27.0/geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64.zip) распаковываете архив и экзешник закидываете в директорию со скриптом
Нужно чтобы Firefox был установлен на машину
Затем `pip install selenium`
Затем:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    opt = FirefoxOptions()
    opt.headless = True
    site = Firefox(options=opt)

    site.implicitly_wait(10)
    site.get('https://www.nike.com/ru/register')

    login = site.find_element_by_name('emailAddress')
    password = site.find_element_by_name('password')
    first_name = site.find_element_by_name('firstName')
    last_name = site.find_element_by_name('lastName')
    birth_day = site.find_element_by_name('dateOfBirth')
    buttons = site.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
    buttons2 = site.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')

    male = 32
    female = 33

    login.send_keys('odin_iz_was@gmail.com')
    password.send_keys('test12=Test')
    first_name.send_keys('Test')
    last_name.send_keys('User')
    birth_day.send_keys('1970-10-20')
    site.implicitly_wait(1)

    buttons[male].click()
    buttons2[14].click()
    # submit.click()

    time.sleep(20)
    site.close()
    site.quit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но мне не нужен селениум/ Мне нужен requets

Comment: К сожалению от Ваших потребностей функционала у requests не прибавится, но если вас смущает открывающееся окно, то его можно и не отображать

Comment: Нет, меня не окно смущает, просто, селениум меня не интересует

Comment: @Jairman Ну "Чем смог помог", удачи